# Unable to load XML validator libraries. XML validation will not be performed

Tags: xml, validation, lxml, py2exe, python-3.8

I'm trying to prduce an .EXE using py2exe.

My code does work perfectly on VS, but when I try to run the exe built with py2exe (or pyinstaller, but discarded since I'm using Python 3.8.5 and there could be compatibility issues) i have this error:

```
WARNING: Unable to load XML validator libraries. XML validation will not be performed
```

This error arises when I try to open a file on my Raspberry using the Pymavlink library. In fact, the error message comes from line 79 of the mavgen.py script but I don't think that the problem stands here since my whole code works nicely from Visual Studio.

In my opinion, it seems like py2exe is not able to find some XML libraries to perform this validation but I'm finding difficulties to "force" py2exe looking for them.

To create the setup script necessary for py2exe, i tried this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['ESEGUI.py'])
```

then, looking for other people having almost my very same problem, i tried to add this workaround, with no gain...

```
setup(
    console=[{'script': 'ESEGUI.py'}],
    options={
        'py2exe': 
        {
            'includes': ['lxml'],
        }
    }
)
```

Any help is really appreciated! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The error is generated by the python file mavgen.py in pymavlink/generator. See the code snipped below.

```
    try:
        from lxml import etree
        with open(schemaFile, 'r') as f:
            xmlschema_root = etree.parse(f)
            if not opts.strict_units:
                # replace the strict "SI_Unit" list of known unit strings with a more generic "xs:string" type
                for elem in xmlschema_root.iterfind('xs:attribute[@name="units"]', xmlschema_root.getroot().nsmap):
                    elem.set("type", "xs:string")
            xmlschema = etree.XMLSchema(xmlschema_root)
    except ImportError:
        print("WARNING: Failed to import lxml module etree. Are lxml, libxml2 and libxslt installed? XML validation will not be performed", file=sys.stderr)
        opts.validate = False
    except etree.XMLSyntaxError as err:
        print("WARNING: XML Syntax Errors detected in %s XML schema file. XML validation will not be performed" % schemaFile, file=sys.stderr)
        print(str(err.error_log), file=sys.stderr)
        opts.validate = False
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception:", e)
        print("WARNING: Unable to load XML validator libraries. XML validation will not be performed", file=sys.stderr)
        opts.validate = False
```

The rest of your error output should indicate what the problem is. For me the problem was solved by adding the following options to pyinstaller. But for you other options might be needed as well depending on your code.

--hidden-import=pymavlink.dialects.v20

--hidden-import=pymavlink.dialects.v20.ardupilotmega